# BaseX XQuery replace

Tags: replace, xquery, basex, xquery-update

I have the following problem. I want to replace a value of an element in my xquery-file by using baseX as the database. The xquery code is as follows:

```
    let $db := doc('update.xml')

replace value of node $db//elem with 'haha'

return <result> {$db//elem/text()} </result>
```

The xml document contains the following elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<root xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<check>
    <ok>
        <elem>test</elem>
        <help></help>
    </ok>
</check>
</root>
```

Everytime I want to execute this xquery an error like this is thrown:

```
Expecting 'where', 'order' or 'return' expression
```

so what should i do or change, to just replace the text "test" by "haha" in the element ? 
If I use just this line of code it works, but I have to read out of URL-Parameter so I need more lines of code, except the "replace...." line!

Answer (score 1):

`let` starts a flwor-expression which may not directly contain update statements. You will have to put a `return` between these two:

```
let $db := doc('update.xml')
return
  replace value of node $db//elem with 'haha'
```

You will also be able to do arbitrary calculations, but make sure not to have any output returned by your query.

There is no [way to use updating statements and return a result at the same time](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/XQuery_Update#Returning_Results).